# Execute code after getting back from an Intent

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView in my main activity.

pressing a button i open another activity and get to the options where i can rename my 
TextView

```
 btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

In my Options activity i rename my TextView like this

```
public class Options extends MainActivity{

public static  Boolean isRenamed;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);

    String lblName = ("Counter 1");
    Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent backToMain = new Intent(Options.this, MainActivity.class);      
            EditText labelName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_name);
            String lblName = labelName.getText().toString();
            backToMain.putExtra(LABEL_NAME, lblName);
            isRenamed = true;
            startActivity(backToMain);
            finish();


        }
    });
}
```

}

I am using the boolean isRenamed and i set it to true after clicking ok

And in my main activity i've set this

```
if (Options.isRenamed == true) {

     // Get the message from the intent
        Intent backToMain = getIntent();
        String lblName = backToMain.getStringExtra(Options.LABEL_NAME);

        // Edit the text view
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1);
        label.setText(lblName);

    }
```

For now it's force closing, but is there some more elegant way to see if i've renamed the file and then execute that piece of code to set it?

Comment: have a look at startActivityForResult(...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. In the Options Activity:

```
public static final int RENAMED = 100;

btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent backToMain = new Intent(Options.this, MainActivity.class);      
            EditText labelName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_name);
            String lblName = labelName.getText().toString();
            backToMain.putExtra(LABEL_NAME, lblName);
            isRenamed = true;
            setResult(RENAMED);
            finish();


        }
    });
```

In MainActiviy, override `onActivityResult()` and
when it is fired check if `resultCode` paramter is equals to RENAMED .

Answer (score 1):

```
Context.startActivityForResult();
```

do all your renaming and other stuff there. return a simple integer to know what happened. That way when you call finish() in your second activity it will return to your first without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

for this senario you need to use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

instead of `startActivity(intent)`

in your `Options` Activity you ca `setResult(resultCode, data)` and call finish.

and in `MainActivity` you can use data in

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, intentsData.REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then change your `TextView` when activity is resumed

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          /**
           * change your TextView
           */
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```